# Why do I keep being made a room owner for rooms made from moved messages?

Tags: discussion, bug, chat

In chat when a moderator moves messages out of the room into their own room it seems to be making the owners of the initial chat room owners of the new room.

This behavior can be seen in this [room-for-lalith-and-fairoz](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29182/room-for-lalith-and-fairoz). It was recently moved out of the PHP chat, but it made all the [PHP owners an owner](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/29182/room-for-lalith-and-fairoz) of that new room.

I first noticed this when I viewed my chat profile and saw I was an owner of at the time 4 additional rooms that were made due to messages being moved out. I requested an admin to remove me from them as I could not, because visiting the access permissions for that room oddly shows the same access permissions for the PHP chat. However, I don't know if they are the same permissions or just a copy though.

Why is this happening and is there a way to prevent this? Random rooms keep being added to the list of rooms owners own.

Comment: I believe the intended effect is to allow moderation of the new room, though I agree, this is odd behavior

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi: I would have assumed if there was a conversation between Alice and Bob and their messages were moved to make their own room, that they would be made the room owners. But I guess that's not how it's being done.

Comment: That's what I'd expect, too.